# Help me install windows 7 on virtual-pc with winxp host

Tags: windows-7, installation, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am running virtualpc on winxp sp3, and i have been trying to install win7, but for the past 2 hrs, it still show the "Expanding windows files (0%).".

The allocated memory is 512MB, and hard drive is 9GB.

what could be wrong?

Comment: is everthing 32bit?

Comment: @dnl Yes my winxp (host system) sp3 is 32bit

Comment: and the guest also?

Answer (score 1):

erm Vista is not Win 7,

But trying increasing memory to 1024MB (1GB), also check how the hard drive emulation is working SCSI or ATA also how fast is your Host should it take agest to install also close all none required software as that will add more load to your CPU

If its Intel check that virtualization is turned on in the bios for your chip it will make a big difference

And at the end of all that if it still does not work head on over the Sun and download Virtual Box and use that.

Comment: @Barkermn01 i don't think this is ram issue. i have installed win7 on a laptop with 512 ram 20GB hard drive sometime ago

Comment: i can agree on the point with virtual box...

Answer (score 1):

OK. I solved the problem.

I simply switched to using VMWare, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Annoyingly that was part of my answer was change visualization software I just said one that was free